SMP Core - How much cache is visible if some cores are disabled
Using BIOS we can disable some cores which makes increases how much L3 core is avaialble to each SMP core. Please note, I am aware the physical L3 cache does not change, but suppose there are 20 cores which has 36m L3 cache, and I disable 19 of them - as far as my understanding goes, all of this L3 cache can be made available to a single core.
This has been discussed here - after some initial confusion - the question was finally answered.
My question is slightly different. Is there a way in software to find out exactly how much L3 cache a particular CPU core can see in a SMP processor ?
For example, if the L3 cache was 36M in a 20 core SMP CPU like that from intel, is there any instruction or MMIO way of verifying the control/status registers to verify how much L3 cache can the active core access ?

I don't think shared cache cares about cores. It may depend on your particular cpu model but if it's "shared" then I don't expect particular slices to be assigned to cores. That said, cpuid instruction does provide cache info you can check but it will probably always give you the total size for L3.
